# mmenu iconbar property is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mmenu

I am trying to make use of the iconbar property of mmenu (here: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/extensions/iconbar.html)

However it is not working properly. I get the menu open as expected once I run the code. Yet when I close the menu, it is first closed completely, then the container slides slightly to right. I think that is some sort of an invisible iconbar pushing the content to the right.
(it shouldn't push anything even if it was visible since I use the menu in front of the application, floating.)

I would appreciate any ideas about the cause & how to fix it.

Here is what I get: http://jsfiddle.net/ozgen92/eqbaf88q/

What should have been happened: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/examples.html
(toggle "iconbar" option at the bottom, extensions section)

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Home</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



<!-- Bootstrap -->  
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"><!--symbols-->
<!-- JS -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>





<!-- Mmenu -->  
<!-- CSS -->
<link href="Libs/jQuery.mmenu-5.3.4/dist/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Libs/jQuery.mmenu-5.3.4/dist/css/extensions/jquery.mmenu.iconbar.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- JS -->
<script src="Libs/jQuery.mmenu-5.3.4/dist/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<!-- JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
        $("#menu").mmenu({
    "extensions": [
      "effect-zoom-panels",
      "iconbar",
      "theme-dark"
    ],
    "offCanvas":{
      "zposition": "front"
    },
    "searchfield": {
      "placeholder": "Search",
      "noResults": "No results found.",
      "add": true
    },
    "navbar": {
      "title": "Main Search"
    },
    "navbars": [
      {
        "position": "top"
      }
    ],
    "sectionIndexer": true
  }, {/* configuration */});

        var API = $("#menu").data( "mmenu" );
    API.open();

    });
</script>

</head>


<body>

<div><!--Wrapper-->
<!--MMENU-->
  <div><nav id="menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Menu1</a>
          <input type="radio" class="Toggle" checked />
        </li>
        <li><a href="/">Menu2</a>
          <input type="radio" class="Toggle" checked />
        </li>
        <li><a href="/">Menu3</a>
          <input type="radio" class="Toggle" checked />
        </li>
      </ul>
  </nav></div>


  <div class="container">
    <h3>Container Example</h3>
    <p>Yes I am a container</p>
  </div>


</div><!--wrapper end-->



</body>
</html>
```

Here is the final image that was suppose to happen: (taken from mmenu, examples section)
[image]

Comment: It's hard to help just by linking a bit of `html` and inline `JS`. Could you try to provide a "live" example of your bug or at least something to play with?

Comment: Sorry for that, I just added a fiddle showing what I get, and a link to a page that has what I would expect.

Answer (score 1):

**The issue:**

For some reasons and because I don't really know how this plugin works, it actually creates a parent `div` to your container with the `.mm-slideout` (the one we are interested in), with the property `transform` set as `none`.

[image: class .mm-slideout before]

But when you *click* to hide the menu, this `transform` property change to `translate3d(60px, 0, 0);` which basically translate your container to *60px* from the left (what you was talking about).

[image: class .mm-slideout after]

**The solution:**

To avoid this effect you don't and because like I said I don't how to configure this, the *simplest* way would be to just avoid this `translate` with:

```
.mm-slideout {
    transform: none !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RedBreast/eqbaf88q/5/

The `!important` actually *is* because it will act as an *override*, give this a **priority**.

There is probably a way to avoid this *class/div* to act like this with a plugin property, but like I said I don't know it and this is the quickest and simplest way to do this even if in term of optimization, I would be better to remove the class.

Hope this is helpful'.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that explains the sliding that I mentioned. I checked it out and it actually exists in one of the mmenu libraries. (jquery.mmenu.iconbar.css)

However it still won't behave as it should have. I added an image showing what mmenu was suppose to do with the code.

Comment: I don't get what you exactly want but I also can't learn the API for you. Provide any bug to help you, try things with options, read their doc...etc. You can't just come and say "*I wan't this working like this*".

Comment: Surely I don't expect you to learn the API. The link I provided had the code and it was suppose to behave in a particular way, thats why your solution wont exactly solve my problem. Im not asking you to make it work, just looking for suggestions. Although it doesnt fix the problem, thanks for your help, really :)